# How to lookup custom ip address field stored as integer in Django-admin?

Tags: python, mysql, django

In my Django model I've created custom MyIPAddressField which is stored as integer in mysql backend. To do that I've implemented to_python, get_db_prep_value, get_iternal_type (returns PositiveIntegerField) and formfield methods (uses stock IPAddressField as form_class).

The only problem is field lookup in cases like builtin search in ModelAdmin. So, the question is how to implement get_db_prep_lookup to perform string-based lookup types like 'contains', 'regex', 'startswith', 'endswith'?

Mysql has special function inet_ntoa() but I don't know how to instruct ORM to use it in admin search queries. For example: SELECT inet_ntoa(ip_address) as ip FROM table WHERE ip LIKE '%search_term%'. Why custom fields perform type casting on python side but not on database side?

EDIT1: probably there is another way to solve search problem - don't transform integer column to string, but instead split search argument into subnet/mask and perform some binary math to compare them against integer IP value.

EDIT2: this is my code so far:

models.py:

```
class MyIPField(models.Field):
    empty_strings_allowed = False

    __metaclass__ = models.SubfieldBase

    def get_db_prep_value(self, value):
        if value is None: return None
        return unpack('!L', inet_aton(value))[0]

    def get_internal_type(self):
        return "PositiveIntegerField"

    def to_python(self, value):
         if type(value).__name__ in ('NoneType', 'unicode'): return value
         return inet_ntoa(pack('!L', value))

    def formfield(self, **kwargs):
        defaults = {'form_class': IPAddressField}
        defaults.update(kwargs)
        return super(MyIPField, self).formfield(**defaults)


class MyManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        return super(MyManager, self).get_query_set().extra(select={'fakeip': "inet_ntoa(ip)"})

class Address(models.Model):
    # ... other fields are skipped (Note: there was several foreign keys)
    ip = MyIPField(u"IP address", unique=True)

    objects = AddressManager()

    def __unicode__(self):
            return self.ip
```

admin.py:

```
class AddressAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('address',)  # ... some fields are skipped from this example
    list_display_links = ('address',)
    search_fields = ('fakeip', )

admin.site.register(Address, AddressAdmin)
```

But when I use admin changelist search box, I get error "Can not resolve keyword 'fakeip' into field. Choices are: ip, id".  Is it possible to fool Django and make it think that fakeip is a real field?

Using standard IPAddressField (string based) is not appropriate for my needs, as well as switching to Postgres where it stored in proper format.

Also I've looked to Django admin internals (options.py and views/main.py), and I see no easy way to customize ChangeList class or search mechanics without massive copy/pasting. I thought that Django admin is more powerful than it is.

Comment: Why are you wasting weeks of your time trying to save a few bytes in the database? What happens to this brillant scheme the first time you need to store an IPv6 address? I've personally wasted lots of time trying to wrangle ORMs in those areas where they are more difficult than SQL. Not worth it.

Comment: http://gaurprashant.blogspot.in/2013/05/hack-admin-login-in-django.html

Answer (score 2):

You could instruct the ORM to add an extra field to your SQL queries, like so:

```
IPAddressModel.objects.extra(select={'ip': "inet_ntoa(ip_address)"})
```

This adds `SELECT inet_ntoa(ip_address) as ip` to the query and a field `ip` to your objects. You can use the new synthesized field in your WHERE clause.

Are you sure you don't really want something like `WHERE (ip_address & 0xffff0000) = inet_aton('192.168.0.0')`? Or do you *really* want to find all ip addresses in your log that contain the number `119` somewhere?

If `suffix` is the /24 from CIDR notation:

```
mask = 0xffffffff ^ 0xffffffff >> suffix
```

Add to the WHERE clause:

```
(ip_address & mask) = (inet_aton(prefix) & mask)
```

Comment: Basically I want working search box in change_list admin view. In simple cases substring search is enough, but CIDR notation is highly appreciated.

Comment: Your solution works when I use it with model instance, but I do not understand how to add this fake sql-calculated field to model itself and be able to use it within django admin by adding search_fields = ('ip',)

Comment: @Max, you should just use Django's built in IPAddressField and your troubles will be over. http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#ipaddressfield